# Выдаёт ошибку name 'what' is not defined

Tags: python

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM(',,,', language ='ru')
print('Calculator has been launched')

init()
print( Back.MAGENTA )
i = 0
while i < 0:
    what = int(input('Что хотите сделать? (+, -, *, /, ^2, Погода, Выйти): '))

if what =='q':sys.exit()
elif what == '^2':
    a =float(input('Введите число: '))
elif what == 'Погода':
    alert = print(',,,')
    place = input(',,,: ')
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()

elif what == '+':
    a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
    b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
elif what == '-':
    a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
    b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
elif what == '*':
    a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
    b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
elif what == '/':
    a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
    b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
elif what == '^2':
    a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
    b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
else:
    print( Back.RED )
    print('Неверный запрос')


print ( Back.GREEN )

if what == '+':
    c = a + b
    print('Результат: ' + str(c))
elif what == '-':
    c = a - b
    print('Результат: ' + str(c))
elif what == '*':
    c = a * b
    print('Результат: ' + str(c))
elif what == '/':
    c = a / b
    print('Результат: ' + str(c))
elif what == '^2':
    c = a * a
    print('Результат: ' + str(c))
elif what == 'Погода':
    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    print('В ' + place + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())
    print('Температура: ' + str(temp) + ' градусов цельсия')
input()
```

При запуске программы, мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    if what =='q':sys.exit()
NameError: name 'what' is not defined
```

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Traceback – это не сама ошибка. Это начало сообщения о ней. Прочитайте, что написано в тексте ошибки и переведите. Это пишут специально для Вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка гласит: **Имя `what` не определено**.

Причина в этих загадочных строках:

```
i = 0
while i < 0:
```

Говорим: "да будет `i` равно нулю" и тут же выполняем цикл, пока `i` **меньше нуля**. С чего бы оно стало меньше-то? Входа в цикл не происходит и переменная `what` не создаётся.

P.S. **Никогда не забывайте, что интерпретатор умный. Он уже рассказал Вам, где ошибка и почему. Вам же осталось только вбить сообщение в переводчик и всё понять. Впредь, пожалуйста, делайте это самостоятельно.**

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но теперь другая проблема. Если ввожу что-то из списка, к примеру '+', то вопрос "Что вы хотите сделать пишется бесконечно, как это исправить?

Comment: @Didj Во-первых, если помогло, примите ответ (галочка). Во-вторых, один вопрос призван решать одну проблему. Задайте другой с новой проблемой и я на него отвечу.

Comment: Нужно подождать 5 минут.

Comment: @Didj Не проблема. Жду :)

Comment: Вопросы раз в 40минут, не могли бы объяснить, в чём же проблема?

Comment: @Didj Минутку, чат создам. Пока погуглите как вообще циклы работают. Может чего и найдёте.

Comment: @Didj А вы код пишете наобум или все же пытаетесь понять что происходит? Про цикл while почитайте хоть что-нибудь.

Comment: @Эникейщик Как я понял проблема в табуляции?

Comment: @Didj Вроде создал, заходите https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98022/https-ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-1018507-d092d18bd0b4d0b0d191d1

Comment: Мне нужно иметь 20 репутации, для общения

Comment: @Didj Тогда мой, а скорее и не только мой, Вам совет. Читайте учебники. Если Вы не знаете, как работает цикл, не следует его использовать, пока не разберётесь. Есть десятки пособий по Python. Спешл фор ю: https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.7.php

Answer (score 0):

Переменная создана внутри цикла, попробуй её создать вне и просто присваивать значение из цикла.

Comment: Как ее вынести из цикла?

Comment: @Didj Я стесняюсь спросить, а Вы код откуда взяли?

Comment: Ни одного входа в цикл осуществлено не будет

Comment: @V-Mor сам писал, вчера начал пробовать что-то делать на Пайтоне, Если короче, то я новичёк.

Comment: @Didj ну да, сам - у Хауди-Хо подсмотрели, но недосмотрели ) Короче, там где у вас `i = 0`, чуть ниже (но до while), объявите `what = ''`